# How do I get the padding token id in huggingface tokenizer for a PAD token

Tags: huggingface-tokenizers

How do I use `[PAD]` instead of the `eos_token_id` when initializing a hugging face model

Answer (score 0):

You need to first initialize the tokenizer with the special token. After that, you can get the id of the token like shwown below.

```py
from transformers import GPT2LMHeadModel, GPT2Tokenizer


tokenizer = GPT2Tokenizer.from_pretrained('gpt2',model_max_length=1024)
tokenizer.add_special_tokens({'pad_token': '[PAD]'})

# To get the token id

encoded_input = tokenizer('<|endoftext|>', truncation=True, padding=False, return_tensors="pt")
print(f"encoded_input {encoded_input}")
# output encoded_input {'input_ids': tensor([[50256]]), 'attention_mask': tensor([[1]])}

answer = tokenizer.decode(torch.tensor([50256]), skip_special_tokens=False)
print(f"answer 50256 {answer}") 
# Ouput answer 50256 <|endoftext|>

# Note 50256 is by default used if nothing is set

encoded_input = tokenizer('[PAD]', truncation=True, padding=False, return_tensors="pt") - 
print(f"encoded_input {encoded_input}")
# output encoded_input {'input_ids': tensor([[50257]]), 'attention_mask': tensor([[1]])}

# and use this in the model

model = GPT2LMHeadModel.from_pretrained(checkpoint_dir,pad_token_id=50257)
model.resize_token_embeddings(len(tokenizer))
```